# How to remove Logo and Menu from CMS Page

Tags: layout-update, cms-pages, magento-2.1.9

I am building a page in Magento 2.1.9 from which I would like to remove the logo and menu. Can this be accomplished through Layout Update XML?

Below is a sample (blank) page. Thanks in advance!

http://www.redballoontoystore.com/test-remove-logo

Answer (score 0):

> Add below line in Content -> Pages -> Home page -> Design -> Layout
>   Update XML

```
<referenceContainer name="logo" remove="true" />
<referenceContainer name="catalog.topnav" remove="true" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately the page is still looking the same. I flushed the cache  to make sure.

Comment: Correction, the logo is gone but the menu is still there.

Comment: Have you using custom theme ?

Comment: Not to my knowledge. At the risk of making you cringe, I didn't build the site so I don't know how the developer did it.

Comment: I am sorry you have to basic knowledge of magento2 programming.

Answer (score 0):

**Create a cms_page_view.xml file in your theme**

> app/design/frontend///Magento_Cms/layout/cms_page_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
     <body>
        
        // Remove logo
        <referenceBlock name="logo" remove="true" />   
                OR
        <referenceContainer name="logo" remove="true" /> 

        // Remove menu
        <referenceBlock name="catalog.topnav" remove="true" />  
                OR
        <referenceContainer name="catalog.topnav" remove="true" />  
        
        <referenceBlock name="breadcrumbs" remove="true"/>     // Remove breadcrumbd
        <referenceBlock name="page.main.title" remove="true"/>  // Remove page title
     </body>
 </page>
```